# Unstacking a multi-index with duplicates

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Date     ID   Value
Mar-20   A     100
Mar-20   B     200
Mar-20   C     300
Apr-20   A     101
Apr-20   B     201
Apr-20   C     301
```

I'm trying to re-shape it so that it looks like this

```
        Value
ID       A      B      c
Date
Mar-20  100    200    300
Apr-20  101    201    301
```

I started off by trying

```
df = df.set_index(["Date", "ID"])
```

But unstacking this let to the following value error: "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"
So I found this suggestion on SO, which allowed me to unstack

```
df = df.set_index(["Date", "ID"].append = True)
```

But when I then unstack by "ID" (ie df = df.unstack("ID") my end dataframe looks like this

```
         Value 
Date     ID     A    B    C
Mar-20   A     100  NaN  NaN
Mar-20   B     NaN  200  NaN
Mar-20   C     NaN  NaN  300
Apr-20   A     101  NaN  NaN 
Apr-20   B     NaN  201  NaN 
Apr-20   C     NaN  NaN  301
```

How can I compress this to get the output I'm after?

Thanks very much

Comment: @YOBEN_S - ya, you are for 75% True, unfortunately this datetimes it a bit complicate.

Comment: @jezrael df.pivot(*df.columns)?

Comment: @YOBEN_S - good point, add to answer.

Comment: @jezrael will reopen heh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for expected output (order of index was changed):

```
df = df.set_index(["Date", "ID"]).unstack()
print (df)
       Value          
ID         A    B    C
Date                  
Apr-20   101  201  301
Mar-20   100  200  300
```

For correct order is possible add [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y')
df = df.set_index(["Date", "ID"]).unstack()
print (df)
           Value          
ID             A    B    C
Date                      
2020-03-01   100  200  300
2020-04-01   101  201  301
```

If need original format in correct order:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y')
df = df.set_index(["Date", "ID"]).unstack().rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))
print (df)
       Value          
ID         A    B    C
Date                  
Mar-20   100  200  300
Apr-20   101  201  301
```

If there are only 3 columns is possible use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), but if more columns it failed, so rather not use it if general data:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y')
df = df.pivot(*df.columns).rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))
print (df)
ID        A    B    C
Date                 
Mar-20  100  200  300
Apr-20  101  201  301
```

If any columns in input data and need pivoting only some 3 columns beter is use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y')
df = df.pivot('Date','ID','Value').rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))
print (df)
ID        A    B    C
Date                 
Mar-20  100  200  300
Apr-20  101  201  301
```

EDIT: If get error:

> Index contains duplicate entries, cannot re-shape

it means there are duplicates per pairs `Date, ID`, so is necessary use aggregate function, like `sum`, `mean` in [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df)
     Date ID  Value
0  Mar-20  A    100 <- same Date, ID
1  Mar-20  A    500 <- same Date, ID
2  Mar-20  B    200
3  Mar-20  C    300
4  Apr-20  A    101
5  Apr-20  B    201
6  Apr-20  C    301



df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y')
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date',
                    columns='ID',
                    values='Value',
                    aggfunc='sum').rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))
print (df)
ID        A    B    C
Date                 
Mar-20  600  200  300 < aggregate sum 100+500=600
Apr-20  101  201  301
```

If need column `Value` in `MultiIndex` use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y')
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date',
                    columns='ID',
                    values=['Value'], 
                    aggfunc='sum').rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))
print (df)
       Value          
ID         A    B    C
Date                  
Mar-20   600  200  300
Apr-20   101  201  301
```

Better solution if need avoid sorting, thanks @anky:

```
df = df.groupby(["Date", "ID"],sort=False)['Value'].sum().unstack()
print (df)
ID        A    B    C
Date                 
Mar-20  600  200  300
Apr-20  101  201  301
```

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back to me. When I try the first version, I get the value error of "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot re-shape". When I add append = True to set_index, I then get loads of different versions of the index (1 for each ID)

Comment: @harrison10001 - Check last paragraph for solution.